# Delete columns based on repeat value in one row in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm hoping to delete columns in my arrays that have repeat entries in row 1 as shown below (row 1 has repeats of values 1 & 2.5, so one of each of those values have been been deleted, together with the column each deleted value lies within).

```
initial_array =

row 0   [[  1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,]
row 1    [0.5,    1,  2.5,    4,  2.5,    2,    1,  3.5,]
row 2    [  1,  1.5,    3,  4.5,    3,  2.5,  1.5,    4,]
row 3    [228,  314,  173,  452,  168,  351,  300,  396]]

final_array =
row 0   [[  1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,]
row 1    [0.5,    1,  2.5,    4,    2,  3.5,]
row 2    [  1,  1.5,    3,  4.5,  2.5,    4,]
row 3    [228,  314,  173,  452,  351,  396]]
```

Ways I was thinking of included using some function that checked for repeats, giving a True response for the second (or more) time a value turned up in the dataset, then using that response to delete the row. That or possibly using the return indices function within numpy.unique. I just can't quite find a way through it or find the right function though.

If I could find a way to return an mean value in the row 3 of the retained repeat and the deleted one, that would be even better (see below).

```
final_array_averaged =
row 0   [[  1,    1,      1,    1,    1,    1,]
row 1    [0.5,    1,    2.5,    4,    2,  3.5,]
row 2    [  1,  1.5,      3,  4.5,  2.5,    4,]
row 3    [228,  307,  170.5,  452,  351,  396]]
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give to a beginner who is stumped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the optional arguments that come with `np.unique` and then use `np.bincount` to use the last row as weights to get the final averaged output, like so -

```
_,unqID,tag,C = np.unique(arr[1],return_index=1,return_inverse=1,return_counts=1)
out = arr[:,unqID]
out[-1] = np.bincount(tag,arr[3])/C
```

Sample run -

```
In [212]: arr
Out[212]: 
array([[   1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ],
       [   0.5,    1. ,    2.5,    4. ,    2.5,    2. ,    1. ,    3.5],
       [   1. ,    1.5,    3. ,    4.5,    3. ,    2.5,    1.5,    4. ],
       [ 228. ,  314. ,  173. ,  452. ,  168. ,  351. ,  300. ,  396. ]])

In [213]: out
Out[213]: 
array([[   1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ],
       [   0.5,    1. ,    2. ,    2.5,    3.5,    4. ],
       [   1. ,    1.5,    2.5,    3. ,    4. ,    4.5],
       [ 228. ,  307. ,  351. ,  170.5,  396. ,  452. ]])
```

As can be seen that the output has now an order with the second row being sorted. If you are looking to keep the order as it was originally, use `np.argsort` of `unqID`, like so -

```
In [221]: out[:,unqID.argsort()]
Out[221]: 
array([[   1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ],
       [   0.5,    1. ,    2.5,    4. ,    2. ,    3.5],
       [   1. ,    1.5,    3. ,    4.5,    2.5,    4. ],
       [ 228. ,  307. ,  170.5,  452. ,  351. ,  396. ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the indices of wanted columns using `unique`:

```
>>> indices = np.sort(np.unique(A[1], return_index=True)[1])
```

Then use a simple indexing to get the desire columns:

```
>>> A[:,indices]
array([[   1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ,    1. ],
       [   0.5,    1. ,    2.5,    4. ,    2. ,    3.5],
       [   1. ,    1.5,    3. ,    4.5,    2.5,    4. ],
       [ 228. ,  314. ,  173. ,  452. ,  351. ,  396. ]])
```

Comment: it is exactly the answer I posted a min ago! but why using np.sort ?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel No it's not, your answer doesn't preserve the order. ;-) Although I didn't see your answer.

Comment: It is fully true, there is a problem with the order.

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you, yours did the job, but I had to give the answer to@Divakar for creating code that gives the mean result, too.

Comment: @georussell Welcome, I think I missed that part, but the Divakar's answer has done the job very well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical grouping problem, which can be solve elegantly and efficiently using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
unique, final_array = npi.group_by(initial_array[1]).mean(initial_array, axis=1)
```

Note that there are many other reductions than mean; if you want the original behavior you described, you could replace 'mean' with 'first', for instance.